# Git does not update branch on repositoy

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gogs

I have a branch named `deliveries` and on this branch, I have made some new changes to some files.

Then I ran the command `git add .` to stage the files. And after that I ran `git commit` (I forgot to add message text).

I closed the Terminal, and tried `git push` to push the updated branch into server but it didn't add the changes.

However when I say `git status`, it says:

`Everything up-to-date`

So how to push the new changes into repository correctly?

Comment: Did it show any error? Did you write the full command? git push - u "url" "branch-name"?

Comment: Did you create a new commit?

Comment: @konekoya Yes I have but didn't add the message for that

Comment: @SimoneLungarella No it justs say Everything up-to-date

Comment: If you have created a new commit, then you should have a new SHA that's different than the upstream one.

Comment: Why you don't read the error message? Because when you `git push` a branch for the first time, you will get an error message stating exactly what you have to do... --> `git push --set-upstream origin deliveries`. Look at the answer from @Hemesh

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a master branch first you have to do this,

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git push # (it will say has no upstream).
git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>
```

Note: `<branch-name>` is the branch which you want to push

Comment: @SwissCodeMen  Thanks, mate for correcting me it was my mistake that I haven't written things clearly, is my answer correct?

Comment: No problem. Yes of course, you answer is correct, so I upvote it :)